# Java Multidimensional Map Values?

Tags: java, arrays

When I use `tag.getValue()` below I get this value: `{permission=test,rank=test,forsale=true}`. How can I extract those values from this Map?

```
List<Map<?, ?>> tagsList = instance.getConfigFile().getMapList("chattags.ranks");

for (Map<?, ?> tagMap : tagsList) {
    for (Map.Entry<?, ?> tag : tagMap.entrySet()) {
        inv.addItem(gui.invItem(Material.NAME_TAG,
                false,
                Methods.color("&e&n" + tag.toString()),
                Methods.color("&e&n" + tag.getValue()),
                Methods.color("&7 - Shows up as: " + tag.getValue())));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am guessing that `tag.getValue()` returns another map. When you toString() a map you get that value. So you will need to access those values like any other map, with the key. So in this instance you would use tag.get("permission"), tag.get("rank")

Comment: Does `tag.getValue()` return an `Object` or something more specific?

Comment: It returns `{permission=test,rank=test,forsale=true}`

Comment: I'm getting this error on the .get: 

`Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'Entry'`

Comment: I think that in order to get an answer that correctly and completely answers your question, you first need to [edit] it and post a [mcve]. For me, there are missing details in your question, for example where is the definition of variable `instance`? Why do you use wildcards as the type parameters for `Map`? Also, it is not clear what you mean by _extract those values from this Map_ Can you post the output you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

Tag is a `Map` to retrieve values from a map you need to use the keys, or, entry set as you are using in the loop. Since the map looks like it is using wildcards you will need to figure out the type of the key and values.

e.g.

```
     List<Map<?, ?>> tagsList = instance.getConfigFile().getMapList("chattags.ranks");

        for (Map<?, ?> tagMap : tagsList) {
            for (Map.Entry<?, ?> tag : tagMap.entrySet()) {
                Object permission = tag.get("permission");
                Object rank = tag.get("rank");
                Object forsale = tag.get("forsale");
                // use values
                inv.addItem(gui.invItem(Material.NAME_TAG,
                                        false,
                                        Methods.color("&e&n" + tagRank.toString()),
                                        Methods.color("&e&n" + tag.getValue()),
                                        Methods.color("&7 - Shows up as: " + tag.getValue())));
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error on the .get: 

`Cannot resolve method 'get' in 'Entry'`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Updated to more closely track your code and now have the nested map.

The below example may help you see clearly how to go about using this data structure.

```
Map<String, Map<?, ?>> tagMapOne = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, String> tagMapTwo = new HashMap<>();
tagMapTwo.put("permission", "test");
tagMapTwo.put("rank", "test");
tagMapTwo.put("forsale", "true");

tagMapOne.put("TagMapTwo", tagMapTwo);

List<Map<?, ?>> tagList = new ArrayList<>();

tagList.add(tagMapOne);

for (Map<?, ?> map : tagList) {
    for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("key=" + entry.getKey() + "|value=" + entry.getValue());
        System.out.println("permission=" + ((Map<?, ?>) entry.getValue()).get("permission"));
        System.out.println("rank=" + ((Map<?, ?>) entry.getValue()).get("rank"));
        System.out.println("forsale=" + ((Map<?, ?>) entry.getValue()).get("forsale"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a null errors with each of those .get commands you suggested

Comment: Can you plug in the generic key/value loop in my example and see what the output looks like?

Comment: I might be somewhat confused, but your example doesn't match the structure of the Map from the YML file

Comment: I added what I'm referring to in my answer.

Comment: I get `Wildcards may only be used as reference parameters` on the `for (? key`

Comment: OK, I updated the last example for the generics you are using.

Comment: Updated to more closely track your code and explicitly show the nested Map

Comment: @tinymothbrain _YML file_ Are you referring to [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) ?

Comment: If you cast the getValue() like I did, you should be able get what you want.  ((Map<?, ?>) entry.getValue()).get("permission")